# What is the simplest way to charge money over the Internet?

Tags: .net, asp.net-2.0, payment

I have a .Net 2.0/3.5 WebApplication.

I want to be able to take money over the internet for my service.

Each of my customers will have an AccountNo.

I wish to offer several products each of which will have fixed price.

I need for my customer to login to my system and elect to pay me money for a product of their choice and for my app to become aware when this is complete so that I may adjust their account to reflect this.

What is the simplest (least complicated coding) way to take their money?

Paypal, NoChex, Google checkout, Something else ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've used 2checkout.com for years and found it to be a good solution.
I eventually switched to regnow but only because I wanted to take advantage of their affiliate network.

Here are some options:

- [2checkout.com](http://2checkout.com)
- [regnow](http://regnow.com) (also has affiliate network)
- [paypal](https://www.paypal.com/) - In contrast to what most people think, you don't need a paypal account to buy from you.
- [Google Checkout](http://checkout.google.com)

Answer (score 14):

[Paypal](https://www.paypal.com/) is fairly straight forward and **secure**.

Comment: Given how many transactions and users they have, it is not surprising there there are complaints.  If you protect yourself and be careful I see no reason to shun paypal.  Their IPN/payment notification is much simpler than google or amazon...

Answer (score 2):

[Amazon Flexible Payment Service](http://aws.amazon.com/fps/)

Answer (score 0):

google and yahoo both offer decent service, and they don't require your customers to create an account.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to bear in mind when choosing a provider is whether you need to have a recurring payment model.  Are your products charged as a one-off fee, or more along a subscription model?  Things like Paypal have limited support for recurring payments.[1]

[1] At least, they did when I investigated it a while ago.  May have changed now.

Answer (score 0):

I've had good experiences with PlugNPay.  Their support staff is responsive and API is easy to use.

http://www.plugnpay.com/