# PHP eCommerce System

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce, shopping-cart, enterprise

I'm looking for a eCommerce system built using PHP and MySQL.

It needs to:

- Be modular (to enable/disabled unused stuff)
- Not include any CMS functionality (so I can supply it myself)
- Not include any user authentication functionality (so I can supply it myself)
- Custom payment methods (so I can intergrate with [DPS](http://www.paymentexpress.com/about/about_paymentexpress/privacy_policy.html))
- Ability to only have a limited amount of fixed products (so no category lists etc)
- Ability to have multiple products/categories/etc
- Be completely skinable
- Have session and saved (logged in) shopping carts
- Functionality for prices, tax rates, multi currency, package and shipping, specials etc
- Free, or Paid with source supplied, support and documentation

Does anyone know of a eCommerce system that comes close to these requirements?

Comment: The ones I know are still under development, but very promissing.

Comment: Sounds like you need an ecommerce "plugin", but i'm not aware of anything that meets your very specific requirements..

Comment: Here's one promissing, that meets all your requirements (it's base on Kohana Framework, but it's under development yet, as far as I know): https://github.com/vendo/vendo

Comment: And THAT's is how you ask a product recommendation! I think @Jeff Would be proud ;) +1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197525/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-charge-money-over-the-internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCart is a nice platform I've been using recently for a client project, that's PHP based, and very customizable.

As many have said, it's a bit odd look for a platform that's missing key elements (i.e. user authentication, etc.) +1 for roll your own, or +1 for Opencart.

Comment: OpenCart looks pretty good, but I will need to look into it in more depth before I can confirm that. I fully think that an eCommerce system should focus fully on its on purpose and not on user authentication, CMS, and templating, etc. From what I have seen so far it looks like OpenCart rolls its own templating system (thats not a no goer though).

Comment: @Petah - I really like how customizable Opencart is, you just have to get used to the file structure. Luckily, the community is quick to respond on the forums if you have any questions. I'm far from a PHP expert, and I could easily navigate the platform to completely create my own design from the ground up.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is probably to search for each of those things as separate elements.

I don't think you'll ever find a solution that is eg. skinable but also has no authentication methods..

It sounds like you should just roll your own or start off with something like http://prestashop.com/ (which I have used somewhat) and make modifications as you see fit.

Comment: From what I have seen from PrestaShop so far I like. I will look into to it more, and in depth to see if it suits my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Since you'll probably lack on replies : https://github.com/vendo/vendo

The only thing it lacks is support / documentation, but that also applies for the framework (Kohana). It's well commented though, very well in fact, and strict OOP.

Comment: Vendo looks promising, but we are not using Kohana. We run a similar framework the was born out of the ashes of CodeIgniter. So I am more looking for a library that is not based around an existing framework. But being that Kohana an our framework use similar principles a port would possibly be feasible.

Comment: @Petah: Kohana was a fork of CI initially, now it's very different. It's pretty stable (I use it on some large-scale websites with no problems) and it's the only one around that makes real use of MVC (being the views real templates by default instead of just plain php files with lots of logic, as for 3.1.0 RC). Worth to give it a try. Also if you need any help porting to it, give me a call.

Comment: Yes I agree that Kohana is a vast improvement of CI. Based on the same principles, but started almost from scratch. Our framework almost ran the same line as Kohana, but we chose to keep ours closed source. Anyway, I will see if Vendo is the right path to go down in the terms of what we are looking for and then get back to you. ;) Tanks for your input.

Comment: You can use components of vendo without kohana, with some re-structuring. The billing module and ACL module for instance, don't rely on any parts of kohana directly, iirc (I'm the author).